# Convergence of a iterative method by $E(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-x^*)^TQ(x-x^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, solution-verification

Consider the optimization problem $\min_{x} f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx-b^Tx$, where $Q$ is positive definite. We apply an iterative algorithm of the form $x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha_kd_k$, where $\alpha_k = -\frac{d_k^Tg_k}{d_k^TQd_k}$, $g_k=Qx_k-b$, and $d^T_kg_k<0$. Given that $(d_k^Tg_k)^2\geq\beta(d_k^Td_k)(g_k^Tg_k)$, where $\beta \in (0, 1)$ is a fixed constant. Determine a constant $c$ in $(0, 1)$ such that $E(x_{k+1}) \leq cE(x_k)$, where $E(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-x^*)^TQ(x-x^*)$ and $x^*=Q^{-1}b$.

My process:

I want to use the provided condition, which means that I want to show that

$$E(x_{k+1})=(1-\frac{(d_k^Tg_k)^2}{(d_k^Td_k)(g_k^Tg_k)})E(x_k) \leq (1-\beta)E(x_k),$$ and set $c=1-\beta \in (0, 1)$.

To achieve this target, let $y_k = x_k-x^*$, and note that $Qy_k=g_k$. Consider $$\frac{E(x_k)-E(x_{k+1})}{E(x_k)}$$,
there is
$$E(x_k)-E(x_{k+1}) = \frac{1}{2}y_k^TQy_k - \frac{1}{2}y_{k+1}^TQy_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}[2(y_k-y_{k+1})^TQy_k-(y_k-y_{k+1})^TQ(y_k-y_{k+1})] = \frac{1}{2}[-2\alpha_kd^T_kQy_k-\alpha_k^2d_k^TQd_k] = \frac{1}{2}[\frac{(d_k^Tg_k)^2}{d_k^TQd_k}]$$.

Then, $$\frac{E(x_k)-E(x_{k+1})}{E(x_k)} = \frac{(d_k^Tg_k)^2}{(d_k^TQd_k)(g^T_kQ^{-1}g_k)},$$
but I can not go further.

How can I simplify the denominator to the desired format?

Comment: Is there $\lambda_1 d^T_kd_k \leq d^T_kQd_k \leq \lambda_n d^T_k d_k$ where $\lambda_1 $ and $\lambda_n$ are the min and max eigenvalues of $Q$?